# composer.phar: download new version or doing self-update?

Tags: composer-php, updates, self-updating

Does it make any difference between updating by `composer.phar self-update` and just replacing composer.phar with a newer version (e.g. with `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`)?

I'm asking this since `composer.phar self-update` makes some problems and I thougt then I will just download a new version. But I'm also wondering if it's just about replacing one single file, why is `self-update` implemented as well? What is the benefit of using this routine?

Comment: The process is different, but the result is the same. Using the most recent composer phar file.

Comment: What happens when you try to update with high verbosity? `composer.phar self-update -vvv`?

Comment: @TomášVotruba `[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                         
  The "https://getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out`. I didn't want to find out what the problem is when I just can download a new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is different, but the result is the same. Using the most recent composer phar file.

The benefits are in easier access. To update, I just type `composer` like I always do when install/update/require new packages, then add `self-update`.

Also when I forget the command, just run `composer` and command list is printed.

One more reason is it's common command in PHAR file ecosystem. PHPUnit, PhpCsFixer and many other have the same command.